# Debian and Cups - Missing SMB

Tags: debian, cups

I want to replace an old server with Debian Stretch and have now installed one with Debian bullseye.

With Debian 11, I am now missing the possibility to insert a printer Windows SMB in Cups.
With "lpinfo -v" the old system still shows me "network smb". With the new one it is missing.

Did I forget to install a package?

```
    apt list --installed | grep samba

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

python3-samba/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
samba-common-bin/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
samba-common/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 all  [Installiert,automatisch]
samba-dsdb-modules/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
samba-libs/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
samba-vfs-modules/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
samba/stable-security,now 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3 amd64  [installiert]
```

Comment: did you check with `dpkg` if you have `Samba` installed?

Comment: I have checked it with apt. I have edited my result above. How should I check it with dpkg?

Comment: Try `apt list --installed | grep smb` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to install smbclient

Comment: If that fixes it, please post it as an answer so we can mark this as answered and the next user with a similar problem can find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had only checked if `samba` is installed. When I also checked for package names including `smb` with

```
apt list --installed | grep smb
```

I noticed that I was missing the package `smbclient`. Installing the package fixed the issue:

```
apt install smbclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Install samba server and client on debian.

`apt-get install samba`

`apt-get install smbclient`

Maybe you will need the **cifs-utils** too

`apt install cifs-utils`